# Identity Server 4: RequestedClaimTypes in IProfileService.GetProfileDataAsync not including IdentityResourceClaims

Tags: identityserver4

I have created my own ProfileService concrete, based on the built in one.

in GetProfileDataAsync(), context.RequestedClaimTypes does not include any related claims from IdentityResourceClaims table, but it does have the IdentityResource from the specified scopes in context.RequestedResources.ParsedScopes. I would think the claims associated with those scopes should be included in RequestedClaimTypes, otherwise is there any way to get these from the context? Or would I need to do my own db query?

Is this example - "app_perms" is the scope (identity resource) and "app" is the related claim (in the IdentityResourceClaims table)

```
    protected virtual async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context, IdentityUser user)
    {
        // since not including claims for IdentityResource scopes, need to check the scope
        if (context.RequestedResources.ParsedScopes.Any(x => x.ParsedName == "app_perms") || context.RequestedClaimTypes.Contains("app"))
        {
            // add some test app claims 
            context.IssuedClaims.Add(new Claim("app", "App1"));
            context.IssuedClaims.Add(new Claim("app", "App2"));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually they can be found here:
context.RequestedResources.Resources.IdentityResources.Any(x => x.UserClaims.ContainsIgnoreCaseTrim("role"))

Answer (score 1):

My impression is that you just set all the available claims in GetProfileDataAsync and then let IdentityServer to decide what claims should end up in the different places (id/access token, userinfo....)

This also simplifies the implementation of the IProfileService

Comment: ok thanks for info, but not very efficient if querying db and setting claims if they aren't being asking for...

Comment: There is also built in support for caching of user data, like here https://github.com/DuendeSoftware/IdentityServer/blob/main/src/IdentityServer/Hosting/DynamicProviders/Store/CachingIdentityProviderStore.cs

also I think its good a good design approach as it makes the storage layer/provider really simple. sure there's more data to return, but at the same time its a tradeof.